# Reference position in CollectionView IOS

Tags: ios, collectionview

Problem with reference position in `CollectionView`

I made a simplified example of my problem. I'm using storyboard with a `CollectionView`, but then I leave that view and return the elements out of place.

The problem occurs after I connect the

```
@ property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UICollectionView * CollectionView;
```

Anyone been through this?
  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rmkkcp99al6czy6/-nL6fUYRQS!

[image with the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlJ1m.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should not have your property names start with a capital letter. They are not classes. Better use `collectionView`.

Second, make sure your collection view is wired up with the appropriate controller in storyboard. You need to connect it to the `delegate` and `datasource` properties. Make sure the view controller implements these protocols.